# Unicode conversion issues

Tags: c++, unicode, c++builder

Here is a beginner question on Unicode. I'm using Embarcadero C++ Builder 2009, where they supposedly changed the default strings to use Unicode.

- I type various symbols in my source editor, that aren't part of the standard "7-bit ASCII".
- My program is using the String type of C++ Builder to fetch user input.
- I am also adding input manually by setting a value to a wchar_t.

It would seem that there are conflicts in how the symbols are interpreted. Sometimes I get a symbol with for example the code 0x00C7 ('Ç'), but sometimes the same symbol is coded as 0xFFC7, for example in the source code editor. To my understanding, the former is proper Unicode, the latter is "something else". Can someone confirm this?

I wonder where this "something else" encoding is coming from, and how to get rid of it?

EDIT: Further research: it seems that one place where the 0xFF** encoding appears is when I do something like this:

```
string str = ...;
wchar_t wch = (wchar_t)str[i];
```

Same result no matter if it is std::string or VCL String. Is `wchar_t` not the same as Unicode?

Comment: if utf-8 is used for encoding then each unicode char could take up 1, 2 or 4 bytes or more. As I understand it wchar_t is always 2 bytes in size per char so that might be the problem.

Comment: @VictorT. Then what character type should I use? I think plain **char** is 8 bit.

Comment: You should use `wstring` not `string` for strings of wide characters (Unicode.)  The new `String` type uses wide chars stored as UTF-16 (don't worry about other encodings such as UTF8 for the moment.)  Your code `string str = ...;` will lose data as it is.  You should then not need the cast in your second line.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing the problem is that in your compiler `char` is signed (the standard allows it to be either signed or unsigned, it's implementation-defined/specific). As such, whenever you convert chars that have bit 7 set to 1 (0x80 through 0xFF) into any larger integer type, it's treated as a negative value and it gets sign-extended to preserve the negative value, or, in other words, this bit 7 gets copied to bit 8, bit 9 and so on, into all higher bits of the bigger integer type. So, 0xC7 can turn into 0xFFC7 and 0xFFFFFFC7. To prevent that from happening, cast `chars` to `unsigned chars` first.

Comment: I have suspected this too, so I carefully use my own uint8 type for chars. However, I suppose **char** might be used internally by some string type or library object.

Comment: C++'s `string` typically uses plain `char` for every string element. If `char` is signed, so is `str[some index]` and is therefore subject to sign extension whenever it's used in expressions (including assignments).

Comment: I just realized that the char literals in the source code are most likely of **char** type, or rather, int truncated to char. They will indeed be interpreted as negative numbers. This explains some of the oddities but not all.

Comment: Character literals, unless they are `L`-prefixed (e.g. `L'A'`) are, well, of type `char`. That is a guarantee in C++. In C they are of type `int` (also signed and will also have sign-extension issues in expressions with longer integers (e.g. `long` and `long long`) and floating-point values).

Comment: Tha'ts new, I had never heard of the L prefix before. I checked C99 and it seems to be identical to C++ in this case. Anyway, I have found a couple of other suspicious places where plain char was used, and it seems that the signedness was indeed causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The wide character type w_type is implementation-defined and need not correspond to the concept of Unicode character. Check out the [description of w_type in the Unicode Standard](http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode6.0.0/ch05.pdf#page=5).

If “Ç” is changed to 0xFFC7, it looks very much like sign extension, i.e. the character is internally stored as byte 0xC7 which is then taken as a signed 8-bit integer and converted to a 16-bit integer with sign extension.

Comment: Are there any guarantees for signedness of wchar_t, is it always unsigned/signed? Because it seems like wchar_t could be the culprit here.

Comment: `wchar_t`'s signedness is not the culprit here. The culprit is the signedness of `char`.

Comment: @Alex Fair enough, but out of curiosity, what does the standard say about signedness of wchar_t?

Comment: According to C99, `wchar_t` is signed and has at least 8 bits in it. It doesn't have to be big enough to support Unicode. If `__STDC_ISO_10646__` is defined, then `wchar_t` supports ISO/IEC 10646's `Unicode required set`. The macro's value indicates the year and month of the 10646 version.