# Hexadecimal to decimal with char giving strange results?

Tags: c++, c

I ran into a very strange problem. I think I am missing some very basic thing here. When I do this:

```
    char buffer[1] = {0xA0};
    int value=0;
    value = (int)buffer[0];
    printf("Array : %d\n",value);
```

I get result as -96, which shouldnt happen. It should give me 160, as hexa number 0xA0 means 160 in decimal. When I put small values in buffer like 0x1F, it works fine.
Can anyone tell me what am I missing here?

Comment: `0xA0 == -96` as an 8-bit signed value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`char` is signed -128 to 127

Declare `buffer` as `unsigned char` or cast to `unsigned char`:

```
char buffer[1] = {0xA0};
int value=0;
value = (unsigned char)buffer[0];
printf("Array : %d\n",value);
```

Comment: Then if I want 160, but I have to use char. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @UnderDog cast to unsigned char, then int, perhaps?

Comment: Actually there is a work around. If I make unsigned char, it works like a charm. #just noticed

Comment: Char being signed on this particular machine is indeed the source of the problem. However this answer falsely suggests that this is always the case.

Comment: -1 The answer is incorrect. char is _not_ signed, you cannot know if it is signed or not. char has implementation-defined signedness. See C11 6.2.5

Comment: char is usually signed. It's been signed on every compiler I've used in a 25 year period. AND it is obviously signed on the posters compiler...

Comment: @MitchWheat Apparently you don't work with embedded systems. Just because you haven't seen a black sheep in 25 years, you cannot make a statement "there are no black sheeps". The signed char type is indeed the culprit in this case, but the code may as well work as the OP expected it.

Comment: you're a real barrel of laughs aren't you? As you stated, it's implementation dependent, and in this case it's the right answer.

Comment: Also, seems a bit rum seeing this answer to one of your questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8587760/unicode-conversion-issues  LOL!